# Failed to load sound using Arcade Library in Python (No decoders available for this file type)

Tags: python, macos, audio, arcade

```
import arcade

arcade.open_window(200, 200, "Sound")
laser_sound = arcade.load_sound("sound1.mp3")
arcade.play_sound(laser_sound)
arcade.run()
```

Hi, im trying to play sound using Python(3.11.3) Arcade Library(2.6.17) using above code but then got error such in the photo below stating FileNotFoundError: Unable to load sound file: "sound1.mp3". Exception: No decoders available for this file type:

[image]

This is how I arranged the file down here:

[image]

Is there anyway to solve this ? oh I've tried using mp3,m4a, ogg and wav format still got the same error.

Comment: Your code works for me. Try this [file](https://file-examples.com/storage/fe0eca90ba64a099e9d0525/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3). If not work try to reinstall Arcade: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall arcade`

Comment: @Alderven I got the same error T,T although I try force install it. Are you using Apple Silicon? where did you put your venv folder? is it inside the same folder or on your Mac? did you install any mp3 software before?

Comment: I'm on Windows. Try to install everything without venv. It gives you a hint where is the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

mp3 files are not supported on MacOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I assume this was the case. Do you got any idea or workaround to solve this ?

Comment: The solution I ended up using was getting compatible file types and then using a try, except statement to define my sound variables differently depending on the os.